# Given $a=r^2\pi h,c=2r\pi h+r^2\pi$, how to find $r$ and $h$ in terms of $a$ and $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given the values of $a$ and $c$ and that
>   $$a=r^2\pi h,\quad
> c=2r\pi h+r^2\pi,$$
>   what are the values of $r$ and $h$?

So recently on a math test, I got this question which I couldn't seem to figure out. It was really boggling my mind and I later found out that I just had interpreted the question wrong, but I was still set on finding out the solution to the problem. I can't seem to do it and wonder if anyone could help.

Comment: You only need the first equation. $$r=\sqrt{\frac a{\pi h}}$$

Comment: How did you interpret the problem?  What do a, and c represent as variables?  It looks like $a$ is the volume of a cylinder with radius r and height h, and $c$ is the surface area of the open cylinder: bottom + sides.

Comment: But @DonThousand, $h$ is unknown as well. So we need two equations to solve for $r$, $h$.

Comment: @DonThousand has shown the answer to the question in the title. To also find $h$, plug that expression into the second equation, that should give you a cubic equation in $\sqrt h$. Those can be solved.

Comment: Doesn't seem pleasant.  From the first, $h=\frac a{\pi r^2}$ and if you substitute that into the second you are led to $\pi r^3-cr+2a=0$, so you have a cubic to deal with.

Comment: $h = \frac{a}{r^2\pi}$ from first equation and then plug that into the second equation and solve for $r$. Once you solve for $r$, you can solve for $h$ as well.

Comment: Can you cite the who gave the exam, and where it was given (university name)?

Comment: Not sure that this will help but I just noticed that $c=\pi (r+h)^2 -\pi h^2$

Answer (score -1):

From the first equation we have that 
$$
2\pi r h = 2\frac{a}{r}
$$
so we can substitute to the second one and then
$$
c=2\frac{a}{r}+r^2 \pi\qquad\text{so}\qquad cr=2a+r^3\pi 
$$
and now the only thing you have to do is to solve this equation using Cardano formula and get that 
$$
r=\frac{\left(\sqrt{81 \pi  a^2-3 c^3}-9 \sqrt{\pi } a\right)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{3}
   c}{3^{2/3} \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 \pi  a^2-3 c^3}-9 \sqrt{\pi } a}}
$$
and now by substituting to the first formula you get 
$$
h=\frac{a}{r^2 \pi}=\frac{3 \sqrt[3]{3} a \left(\sqrt{81 \pi  a^2-3 c^3}-9 \sqrt{\pi }
   a\right)^{2/3}}{\left(\left(\sqrt{81 \pi  a^2-3 c^3}-9 \sqrt{\pi }
   a\right)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{3} c\right)^2}
$$

Comment: so using the Cardano formula you get the solution for r and then you substitute r to the first equation and get the $h$ value

Comment: @amWhy now you have the result in answer